# Firebase Swift equivalent of push()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Javascript, calling push on a firebase ref would generate a random ID. Then you can populate the stuff below.

However, I can't find push in Swift. Do I have to generate random IDs myself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`childByAutoId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-childbyautoid):

> `childByAutoId` generates a new child location using a unique key and returns a FIRDatabaseReference to it. This is useful when the children of a Firebase Database location represent a list of items.
>
> The unique key generated by childByAutoId: is prefixed with a client-generated timestamp so that the resulting list will be chronologically-sorted.
>
> *Declaration*
>
> ```
> func childByAutoId() -> FIRDatabaseReference
> ```

Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: Thank you! I was scrolling through the docs looking for the word push but it wasn't there